# How can I access the Apify SDK within the Pagefunction with PhantonJS Scraper

Tags: apify

I am using the [Apify Phanton crawler](https://apify.com/apify/legacy-phantomjs-crawler). Inside of the [PageFunction](https://apify.com/apify/legacy-phantomjs-crawler#page-function), I would like to access the Apify SDK, which you can do with the other [Apify cheerio-scraper](https://apify.com/apify/cheerio-scraper#page-function) and [Apify puppeteer-scraper](https://apify.com/apify/puppeteer-scraper#page-function).

I noticed the PhantonJS crawler context does expose the Apify object, while the others do.

One possible solution would be to [inject jquery](https://apify.com/apify/legacy-phantomjs-crawler?section=input-schema) in the pageFunction and use the [Apify web API](https://docs.apify.com/api/v2).

Answer (score 1):

The phantom or Web Scraper doesn't expose the `Apify` variable because the pageFunction runs in the browser context and the SDK exists in the Node.js (server) context. You can use our API with the `fetch` or `JQuery.ajax`. Just tick on the `disableWebSecurity` so you get rid of CORS problems.

Comment: thanks. could you please include some example code?

Comment: What do you need to call from there?

Comment: So you need this endpoint - https://docs.apify.com/api/v2#/reference/datasets/item-collection/put-items

```await fetch('https://api.apify.com/v2/datasets/datasetId/items?token=soSkq9ekdmfOslopH', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(result),  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}}
)```